# SOQL - Convert Date To Owner Locale

Tags: sql-server, salesforce, soql

We use the DBAmp for integrating Salesforce.com with SQL Server (which basically adds a linked server), and are running queries against our SF data using OPENQUERY.

I'm trying to do some reporting against opportunities and want to return the created date of the opportunity in the opportunity owners local date time (i.e. the date time the user will see in salesforce).

Our dbamp configuration forces the dates to be UTC.

I stumbled across a date function (in the Salesforce documentation) that I thought might be some help, but I get an error when I try an use it so can't prove it, below is the example useage for the convertTimezone function:

```
SELECT HOUR_IN_DAY(convertTimezone(CreatedDate)), SUM(Amount)
FROM Opportunity
GROUP BY HOUR_IN_DAY(convertTimezone(CreatedDate))
```

Below is the error returned:

```
OLE DB provider "DBAmp.DBAmp" for linked server "SALESFORCE" returned message "Error 13005 : Error translating SQL statement: line 1:37: expecting "from", found '('".
Msg 7350, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot get the column information from OLE DB provider "DBAmp.DBAmp" for linked server "SALESFORCE".
```

Can you not use SOQL functions in OPENQUERY as below?

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    OPENQUERY(SALESFORCE,'
        SELECT HOUR_IN_DAY(convertTimezone(CreatedDate)), SUM(Amount) 
        FROM Opportunity 
        GROUP BY HOUR_IN_DAY(convertTimezone(CreatedDate))')
```

UPDATE:

I've just had some correspondence with Bill Emerson (I believe he is the creator of the DBAmp Integration Tool):

> You should be able to use SOQL functions so I am not sure why you are
>   getting the parsing failure. I'll setup a test case and report back.

I'll update the post again when I hear back. Thanks

Comment: can you post your OPENQUERY code?

Comment: I've just added the full OPENQUERY code I'm running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new version of DBAmp (2.14.4) has just been released that fixes the issue with using ConvertTimezone in openquery.

> ## Version 2.14.4
>
> - Code modified for better memory utilization
> - Added support for API 24.0 (SPRING 12)
> - Fixed issue with embedded question marks in string literals
> - Fixed issue with using ConvertTimezone in openquery
> - Fixed issue with "Invalid Numeric" when using aggregate functions in openquery

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure that because DBAmp uses SQL and not SOQL, SOQL functions would not be available, sorry.

You would need to expose this data some other way. Perhaps it's possible with a [Salesforce report](https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/reports_overview.htm), [web-service](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_CSH.htm#apex_web_services_methods.htm), or compiling the data through the program you are using to access the (DBAmp) SQL Server.

If you were to create a Salesforce web service, the following [example](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_CSH.htm#sforce_api_calls_soql_select_convert_time_zone.htm) might be helpful.

```
global class MyWebService 
{
    webservice static AggregateResult MyWebServiceMethod() 
    {
        AggregateResult ar = [
            SELECT 
                HOUR_IN_DAY(convertTimezone(CreatedDate)) Hour, 
                SUM(Amount) Amount 
            FROM Opportunity 
            GROUP BY HOUR_IN_DAY(convertTimezone(CreatedDate))];

        system.debug(ar);
        return ar;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Matthew for the response, I've not heard back from Bill, but just been looking at the dbamp documentation and it does state that it handles SOQL: "When additional join performance is needed, consider using the OPENQUERY clause with DBAmp. Using OPENQUERY allows you to pass salesforce.com SOQL statements (not SQL) directly to DBAmp. A full description of the SOQL language can be found on the salesforce.com website."